Change colors in double y-axis plot
I have a two y-axis plot. The reproducible example looks like this:
library(plotly)
library(lubridate)
year  <- c(2011:2019)
data1 <- c(2, 3, 2, 5, 1, 8, 2, 7, 9)
data2 <- c(20, 30, 20, 50, 10, 80, 20, 70, 90)
dataset <- data.frame(year, data1, data2)

dataset$year <- lubridate::parse_date_time(dataset$year, orders = "%Y")
dataset$year <- as.Date(dataset$year)
plot_ly() %>%
  add_trace(x = dataset$year, 
            y = dataset$data1,
            type="bar",
            #mode="lines+markers",
            yaxis="y", 
            name="yaxis data",
            color = "red") %>%
  add_trace(x = dataset$year, 
            y = dataset$data2,
            type="scatter", 
            mode="lines+markers",
            yaxis="y2", 
            name="yaxis2 data",
            color = "blue") %>%
  layout(yaxis=list(side="left"),
         yaxis2=list(side="right",overlaying="y"),
         showlegend=TRUE)

The code works fine except the color part. How to specify colors for the line and bar in the plot?

Could you please share some reproducible data using dput?

You can set the colors for the traces using the marker= and line= attributes:
library(plotly)

plot_ly() %>%
  add_trace(
    x = dataset$year,
    y = dataset$data1,
    type = "bar",
    # mode="lines+markers",
    yaxis = "y",
    name = "yaxis data",
    marker = list(color = "red")
  ) %>%
  add_trace(
    x = dataset$year,
    y = dataset$data2,
    type = "scatter",
    mode = "lines+markers",
    yaxis = "y2",
    name = "yaxis2 data",
    marker = list(color = "blue"),
    line = list(color = "blue")
  ) %>%
  layout(
    yaxis = list(side = "left"),
    yaxis2 = list(side = "right", overlaying = "y"),
    showlegend = TRUE
  )


